# Does initializing a Q-table with zeros introduce bias towards the first action in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm working on a reinforcement learning problem where I've initialised the Q-table with zeros. I noticed that when all Q-values for different actions are initially set to zero, the arg-max function tends to select the first action when multiple actions have the same Q-value.

Doesn't this create a potential bias towards the first action? Is it a bad idea to initialise Q Table with zeroes. If so what else should be done?

I tried initialising Q Table with zeroes and it works. However where the Q values are still zeroes, the first action is selected. For example, in the goal state, all values would be zero and the first action is selected. I was under the impression that any action is acceptable in the goal state, but I have found different behaviour for other actions. If I initialise it with values other than zero wouldn't it still give the same result?

Comment: In a discrete state space case by design no (if you run it for long enough), because after enough exploration it'd converge to the same Q-table and model (to make it really converge in practice, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724748/19626271)). In continuous state space this is not so easy, because you cannot explore all states in finite time therefore convergence isn't guaranteed (happens often in practice though, depends on the problem), at least not with the basic Q-learning algorithm. If you can discretize your environment well, e.g. in the CartPole game, it again won't matter

Comment: Yes, but the problem is not that it doesn't converge. It is that wherever the Q values are zero for all available actions, the first action will be selected. For example, say actions 0 is left and 1 is right, then wherever the values are all zeroes (or same values) the action left would be chosen. Does this cause a problem of bias or can this be ignored?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right, it will introduce some bias.

The algorithm will converge to the optimal solution regardless of what initial values we start with, so that won't be much of a problem in the long run.

It will affect the rate of convergence, though. As an example, if we set the initial values high, the agent will be incentivized to explore more which will slow down the rate of convergence.

In general, intialising values to 0 should be fine, but I'll let someone else give a more detailed response for which values would be pragmatically better (and in what situations).

Comment: Thank you.
Yes that does make sense and it does converge. I was only concerned with whether that bias is a problem that can be solved or whether it should be ignored.